# Lance.gg in multiplayer html5 game does not sync

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, multiplayer, lance

I'm trying to make a `multiplayer game in HTML5`. I found lance.gg and play around. I modified the Pong game like this.

- remove Paddle (only Ball left)
- set gravity to `(0, 0.1)`
- set `Ball.velocity.y = -3` each time keyboard input space bar

And here is result https://youtu.be/MmQOqR71Df0. As you can see, it does not really sync over the window. How can I make it move smoothly between many players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ball.js` class defines the following getter:

```
get bendingVelocityMultiple() { return 0.0; }
```

This instructs the client to ignore the server's velocity updates. The result is that the client and server velocities fall out-of-sync, and results in the video you captured.

If you set instead:

```
get bendingVelocityMultiple() { return 0.8; }
```

Then the problem will go away.  Having `bendingVelocityMultiple` set to zero might be useful in other cases though, for example if you want to transplant the ball back to the center when a player has lost.

Take a look at the [documentation for GameObject](http://docs.lance.gg/r2.0.6/GameObject.html#.bendingVelocityMultiple)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Can you tell me how to create a ground object ? Like when the ball hit the ground, it stop falling. And how to detect if it hit some other objects with special shape ?

Comment: You may want to ask this as a separate question.  But the gist of it is that you may not need a game object for the ground, since the ground does not need to synchronize to all players.